# Ltac: do something different in each goal

Tags: coq, dependent-type, theorem-proving, coq-tactic, ltac

I've got a proof script where I'm exploring multiple cases, and it's currently quite slow, since I have a number of strategies for solving the goals, and I'm trying each one in each case.

I know that I need to apply certain tactics in certain cases, but I'm unsure of how to do this.

Here's what I have now:

```
induction e;
    intros;
    pose (bool_dec (is_v_of_expr e1)) as ve1; destruct ve1;
    [> thing1 | thing 2].
```

which gives the error `Incorrect number of goals (expected 26 tactics, was given 2)`.

I'm trying to do `thing1` in the first goal from `destruct` and `thing2` in the second goal from `destruct`, for each case generated by induction.

The problem is, `induction` generates 13 subgoals, each of which gets split into 2 by `destruct`. The local selector `[> thing1 | thing2 ]` is trying to match *all* subgoals, not just the ones produced by the particular destruct.

How can I sequence the tactics, so that `destruct` is run on each case generated by induction, then `thing1` is run on the first destruct-generated goal, and `thing2` is run on the second generated goal, for each induction case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>You have two problems: (1) semicolons are left-associative by default, and (2) the `[> ]` syntax applies to all focused goals, rather than only the ones produced by the previous tactic.</s>
(As pointed out by Jason, this explanation isn't right, but the answer still works :)

You can solve these problems by changing `[> ]` to `[ ]` and right-associating the semicolons with parentheses:

```
Goal ((True /\ True) /\ (True /\ True) /\ (True /\ True)).
  Fail (split; [|split]); split; [> exact I | exact I].
  (split; [|split]); (split; [exact I | exact I]).
Qed.
```

In your example:

```
induction e; intros;
  pose (bool_dec (is_v_of_expr e1)) as ve1;
  (destruct ve1; [thing1 | thing 2]).
```

Comment: Actually, `;` is fully associative, and `; [...]` binds more loosely than `;` and is left associative.  Also, all tactics are implicitly multigoal, and apply to all currently focused goals.